# Help with substituting definitions into tensor

Tags: tensors, multilinear-algebra

I have 4 definitions for the following (Einstein summation) tensor

$A^{ijk}A^{*}_{ijk}=A^{111}A^{*}_{111}+3(A^{112}A^{*}_{112})+3(A^{122}A^{*}_{122})+A^{222}A^{*}_{222}$

If I have these 4 definitions and sub them in,

$(A^{111}=a)$, 
$(A^{112}=b)$,
$(A^{122}=c)$, 
$(A^{222}=d)$

Would the result look like this?

$a^{2}+3b^{2}+3c^{2}+d^{2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $i,j,k=1,2$. Using Einsten's summaton convention:

$$A^{ijk}B_{ijk}:=A^{1jk}B_{1jk}+A^{2jk}B_{2jk}=\left(A^{11k}B_{11k}+A^{12k}B_{12k}  \right)+\left(A^{21k}B_{21k}+A^{22k}B_{22k}\right)=\\
A^{111}B_{111}+A^{112}B_{112}+
A^{121}B_{121}+A^{122}B_{122}+
A^{211}B_{211}+A^{212}B_{212}+
A^{221}B_{221}+A^{222}B_{222};
$$

**If** both $A$ and $B$ are symmetric in $i,j$, then

$$A^{ijk}B_{ijk}=A^{111}B_{111}+3A^{112}B_{112}+
3A^{122}B_{122}+A^{222}B_{222},  $$

as you stated. If $B_{\bullet \bullet}:=A^{*}_{\bullet \bullet}$, denoting by $*$  complex conjugation we arrive at

$$A^{ijk}B_{ijk}=|a|^2+3|b|^2+
3|c|^2+|d|^2,  $$

where
$$A^{111}=a,$$
$$A^{112}=b,$$
$$A^{122}=c,$$
$$A^{222}=d, $$

and $|\cdot|$ is the modulus of complex numbers.

Comment: Hey, thanks Avitus!!  I asked this question awhile back.. I appreciate you answering it!  Is it possible to predict how many terms will be in the tensor product when expanded? Since we have 3 indices and 2 choices for $ijk$ (either 1 or 2), is it true that the terms will be equal to $(choices)^{indices}$ or $2^{3}=8$?